# Google play service sample not getting location offline

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services, android-fusedlocation

I'm working on location based app. I am using `LocationUpdatesForegroundService` sample code.
Which is a `Service` to get location details

At some case location are not getting.

like.

**GPS and Internet are on I'm getting location details**.

but,

**GPS and Internet are in offline I'm not getting location details.**

**case :**
Start app I am start to service getting location but `gps` off case to first prompt to please `gps` ON after I `gps` ON.

BUT not getting LOCATION `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation` method `task.getResult()` are `null`.

please resolve my issue.

Thanks

**NOTE:
This code working in MOTO E os version 4.4.4.
but not working in LAVA a97 os version 6.0**

I'm using this sample :-
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService

Comment: Got the same... Following all the tutorials, but always get null

Answer (score 0):

You can get only details by getting `LocationUpdates` in `textview` maps won't give you updates in `offline`.If you are using textview for getting updates You may forgot this.

add `CourseLocation` Permisssion in Manifest.xml

Comment: you means <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: ok. But why you are starting service and i dont know why you are doing.
I think to get Location details there is no need of a service

Comment: I need accurate gps. That's why I'm following google's official sample. if you have another good example for getting gps offline please let me know

Comment: Can i give another answer which different from yours.
You don't need the service in my code but it will give you accurate results

Comment: I'm not sure that will it give are not. i code this one long ago. if you need i can give you

Comment: yeah sure, Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159979/discussion-between-lokesh-kanumoori-and-vishal).

Answer (score -1):

In `onCreate()`

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
  makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };
// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and finally don't forget to add permission in manifest and handle the permissions in Java code too because of `dynamic permissions`.

That's it.

I hope it will work fine even in offline also.

Comment: Is it useful to you ?